# Meteor 1.3 simple-todo not working for me on Windows 10

Tags: javascript, meteor, windows-10

I am following this tutorial, which is Meteor 1.3's official tutorial:

https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/templates

After importing 'body.js' file in 'main.js' its not showing up on the page.

Here is the source code:
https://github.com/blackmamba/simple-todos

Would appreciate any help.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to import `./main.html` in `main.js` [Here](https://github.com/blackmamba/simple-todos/blob/master/client/main.js#L4)

I changed it and it worked, I've also sent you a pull request to your repository which you can merge [here](https://github.com/blackmamba/simple-todos/pull/1).

Comment: To elaborate: this is because everything in the client folder is still being automatically loaded by Meteor 1.3. There are plans to change this but not in the immediate future.

Comment: Thanks @the joker I'll give it a try. The tutorial requires you to add the '.html' file. Is that a bug?

Comment: Thanks @brownmamba